# how to add specific role to an action that has a global authorization on controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I have Controller that has a Authorization for Specific Role.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "admin")]
public class PanelController : Controller
{

}
```

Now I want One my Actions have been also accessible for role user
but i doesnt work when I do this

```
[Authorize(Roles = "admin")]
public class PanelController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [Authorize(Roles = "admin,user")]
    public ActionResult MyAction()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

in MyAction Method the user with role user have no access.
I use asp.net mvc5 and identity 2.
I would be very pleased if someone would help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The effect of Authorization attributes when applied to both Controller and Action is to `AND` the roles. Hence in this case your `User` role will not work as your Controller attribute is going to invalidate the AND operation being carried out.

You could use `User` role on the Controller and apply `Admin` role to all other Actions. This will work provided your Admins have the User role assigned to them.

Comment: i knew that. but my actions are so many so I wanted another way to do that. thank you so much for your answer